# ember-simple-auth and Implicit Grant authentication: use authenticateSession test helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

If a User is not authenticated, I redirect him to a corporate login page:

```
https://super-secret-gateway/authorization.oauth2?client_id=XXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callback&response_type=token&scope=profile%20openid
```

Once he is authenticated after entering his username and password, he is redirected back with the following URL

```
https://myapp/callback#access_token=2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA&type=Bearer&expire_in=3600&state=myAppRandomState
```

I can't figure out how to use `authenticateSession` test helper in this case.
The ESA docs have no detailed example about that and the way I do it is not working:

```
module('Acceptance | Dashboard', function(hooks) {
  setupWindowMock(hooks);
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);
  setupMirageTest(hooks);

  test('Authenticated users can visit /dashboard', async function(assert) {
    let shop = this.server.create('shop');
    this.server.create('user', { shop });

    await authenticateSession({
      token: 'abcdDEF',
      token_type: 'Bearer'
    });

    await visit('/dashboard');

    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/dashboard', 'user is on dashboard page');
  });
});
```

It seems like the problem is due to the use of `window.location.replace` in my `index` route:

export default Route.extend(UnauthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  session:      service('session'),
  routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated: 'dashboard',

```
  beforeModel: function() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    if (!this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
      let oauthUrl = config.oauthUrl;
      let clientId = config.clientID;
      let redirectURI = `${window.location.origin}/callback`;
      let responseType = `token`;
      let scope = `profile%20openid`;
      window.location.replace(oauthUrl
                            + `?client_id=${clientId}`
                            + `&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}`
                            + `&response_type=${responseType}`
                            + `&scope=${scope}`
      );
    }
  }
```

To get around this problem, I have to use [ember-window-mock](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-window-mock) add-on. But event in this case, the problem is still there. The point is when I use this assertion:

```
assert.equal(window.location.href, '/dashboard', 'user is on dashboard page');
```

the test displays the difference of `window.location.href` pointing to the login page instead of `/dashboard`.
If I use this assertion:

```
assert.equal(currentURL(), '/dashboard', 'user is on dashboard page');
```

the difference is:

```
Expected:|"/dashboard"|
|Result:|"/"|
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the redirect works? That has been the cause of all our trouble with that kind of authentication workflow.

Comment: @Bracke: first, I had to change `token` to `access_token`, that's what ESA sends back, unfortunately, the official README has no mentions about that. Another point is if I put a breakpoint in `index.js`, I'll update the post in several seconds, the value of the condition `if (!this.get('session.isAuthenticated'))` is true and I'm still redirected to the external login page.

Comment: What does `this.get('session.data')` result in?

Comment: @Bracke If I add `console.log` to `index` route just before the `if` clause, it sends `[object Object]`

Comment: Right. how about `this.get('session.data.authenticated')`? According to http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/SessionService.html it should contain "the session data that the authenticator resolved with when the session was authenticated (see authenticate) and that will be cleared when the session is invalidated."

Comment: @Bracke when running the app, it sends correctly `{authenticator: "authenticator:oauth2-implicit-grant", access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCSI…", token_type: "Bearer", expires_in: "7199"}`. In tests it is just empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188336/discussion-between-belgoros-and-bracke).